# Printing out traces to be read by a memory simulation application in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, hex, storage

Trying to print out large traces of memory addresses (32 bits) for 2^32 addresses in the following manner:

0x12345678 W

0x23456789 R

.

.

.

.

0xFFFFFFFF W

Basically going from one address to the other. So it could be going from 0x0000000 to 0x00000003, we would have 0x0000000 R, 0x0000001 R, 0x0000002 R, 0x0000003 W.

Main goal is to feed them to a simulator but I am having storage and memory issues printing these (using print()) and storing them in a file in Python. I can't compress them because the simulator takes them in the above fashion. What is a good, efficient way to print them and store them in Python?

Comment: what does your input look like? Note printing 4 billion anything to the screen will take a while. `print()` is fairly slow

Comment: @JonSG input is basically going from one address to the other. So it could be going from 0x0000000 to 0x00000003, we would have  0x0000000 R,  0x0000001 R,  0x0000002 R,  0x0000003 W. 
If I were to directly to write to a file, how would I do it instead of a print? I don't need to see them on the screen

Comment: With what you describe, you shouldn't have *"memory issues"*. Maybe you're doing something bad. Can't tell when you keep your code secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by using just a file (for larger results) as `print()` is kind of slow. Maybe:

```py
start = 0
end = 4
w_or_r = ["R", "W"]
with open("results.txt", "w") as file_out:
    for i in range(start, end):
        file_out.write(f"0x{i:08x} {w_or_r[i % 2]}\n")
```

That should give you a file like:

```
0x00000000 R
0x00000001 W
0x00000002 R
0x00000003 W
```

Comment: @KellyBundy Sure, one can technically use `print()` to write to a file. For the novice though, I think it is better to explicitly use  `file_out.write(<stuff>)` rather than `print(<stuff>, file=file_out)`.

Comment: Or they might just pipe the output into that other program, that's what *"feed them to a simulator"* sounds like to me.

Comment: @KellyBundy That is an excellent observation.

Comment: The simulation takes in a file containing traces, so this is the correct approach. Thank you!

Comment: Though yes, I just tested your code with `end = 10**6` and it took ~0.75 seconds and with `print(f"0x{i:08x} {w_or_r[i % 2]}", file=file_out)` it took ~1.25 seconds, so it's indeed significantly slower.

Answer (score 1):

To efficiently generate and store 2^32 memory addresses in Python, consider writing them directly to a file in a loop without storing them in memory. Use string formatting for hexadecimal conversion and write each line to the file immediately. This approach minimizes memory usage.

basic script:

```py
def generate_addresses(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        for i in range(2**32):
            address = f"0x{i:08X}"
            access_type = "W" if i % 2 == 0 else "R"
            file.write(f"{address} {access_type}\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_addresses("memory_addresses.txt")
```

This script alternates between 'W' and 'R' for each address and writes directly to a file, which is efficient for such large-scale data handling.

Comment: basically going from one address to the other. So it could be going from 0x0000000 to 0x00000003, we would have 0x0000000 R, 0x0000001 R, 0x0000002 R, 0x0000003 W but your style of generating the address and writing it out to a file is essentially what I am looking for. Thank you.